# A question about UIEvent

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

My question is is it possible to tell from an UIEvent object whether it is a tap touch or a sweep touch ?   Have checked the documentation, UIEvent has type and subtype properties.  But their possible values seem to only differentiate between tap and device motion.  The subtype values also seem to only indicate motion subtypes.

Wish to tell the difference between a single tap and a sweep tap.  Hope that somebody could help ...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sweep tap".

Comment: What I meant about sweep touch is when you tab, then move and then finally release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GestureRecognizer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Have actually used GestureRecognizer, and it is useful in most cases.  But when I need to do it in HitTest, the Recognizer (and its subclasses) would not be able to do the job.

Comment: Rahul is right, it may be impossible or difficult for HitTest to know what kind of touch it is, since touch gestures could be defined by a series of touches.

Comment: @Stanley HitTest should not be used.